TI LMK04828 , two questions, bipolar or sine wave modes, LVCMOS/LVTTL or sine wave
I am using an external clock source to drive the clocks on an embedded system. This is done by seating an add-on board and then plugging in something that looks like an RF SMA into said add-on board. The add-on board contains the Texas Instruments IC, LMK04828B which is a kind of sophisticated programmable clock generator.
**
QUESTION 1
**
During programming of the LMK04828B, I must set the CLKin0_TYPE to either Bipolar=0 or MOS=1. Which one should I use?
Here is everything I know about the incoming signal.
Rated : ~1.4 Vpp , Square Wave, 50 ohm impedance, single-ended.
Measured : 2.00V max, generally Squarish wave. 10MHz
Below is the signal seen on oscilloscope.

I have no idea whether this is AC coupled or DC coupled. Nothing mentioned in the spotty literature, although I may be able to post the schematics if that allows us to puzzle this out. The literature on the setting is shown,

.

**
QUESTION 2
**
Is this connection safe to make? The DUTs used are different manufacturers, and I do not want to destroy sensitive electronics. The SMA port connects to pin CLKin0. Elec Characteristics are shown,


The signal, as shown on the scope, is digitally-generated but DC decoupled, which makes it close to AC sinwave. Therefore you should follow TI recommendations for Figure 27.
